# add class when click in a link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

it removes the class but it doesn't add the class, i can't use `.click()` function it needs to be `onclick=""`

```
<li class="selected"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myfunction(x,y,x)">Click me</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myfunction(x,y,z)">Click me</a></li>

function myfunction(a,b,c){
    $('ul li.selected').removeClass('selected').addClass('none');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: Your `onclick` is doing nothing useful as shown. Change it to `onclick="myfunction.call(this)"`

Comment: Why can you not use `.click()`?

Comment: i have more codes in this function and i'm using `myfunction(x,y,z)` will it work? @CrazyTrain

Comment: cuz i have to pass some parameters in this funcion @Dom

Comment: @EddieD.: If you're actually invoking the function *(your code shows no invocation)*, you still need to set its `this` value. That's why I used `.call(this)`. So then you'd do `myfunction.call(this, x, y, z)`

Comment: i forgot to put in my question, i've edited it @CrazyTrain

Comment: ...though you don't need to use an onclick attributes to pass arguments to a function.

Comment: even if these arguments are php values? @CrazyTrain

Comment: @EddieD.: You'd need to relate them to the elements somehow *(I assume each one has unique values)*. People usually use `data-` attributes for this. Though attribute handlers works fine too.

Comment: it worked with ur hint `.call(this)` @CrazyTrain

Answer (score 4):

You are already using jQuery, so just use jQuery to handle all your events.

Add this code;

```
$(function(){

    // bind click event to your <a> tags
    $('a').click(function(e){
        // prevent the default behaviour of your links
        e.preventDefault();
        // remove the class from all li's
        $('li').removeClass('selected');
        // add selected to the clicked a's parent li
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
    });

});
```

Then keep your html clean from JavaScript

```
<li class="selected">
    <a href="#">Click me</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Click me</a>
</li>
```

**p.s.**

If you are wanting to put PHP in, then you could put things in like;

```
// check out my 1337 php coding skillz!
<a href="#" data-foobar="<?php echo something ?>">Click Me</a>
```

Then access it in your jQuery using

```
$(this).data('foobar');
```

**pps**
*Sorry my php coding skills are rubbish!*

Comment: i'm not sure if i can use `.click()` cuz i use some PHP values in this function.. there is an ajax function inside my function

Comment: @EddieD. then store the PHP values in some variables in a script tag.

Comment: @EddieD. You can put php code within it as long as the JavaScript is on the same page. You can put Ajax in it, etc... If you are working with Ajax though and want to attach events to Dynamically added content, then take a look at using the `on()` event handler.